# How to get imei number galaxy s5active

Tags: hardware

My phone was left in a friends car and I need the imei number

Answer (score 1):

You can visit https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard from your Desktop/PC.

Provide your Google Account details to sign-in(username and password) that you used while setting up your Android device.

You need to expand the Android tab. Here you will see List of all Android devices that are connected to your Google Account and it will list the IMEI number of your phone as well.

Below is the example:

[image]